# MySQL Combine row values with comma and more

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have been banging my head over this for a while. Mainly it's not about getting a solution BUT how it works. It would be great if you can give explanation on how the solution is implemented.

This is just sample data, I am working with 5 tables with inline SELECT statements. Thank you SQL Gurus.

### Sample Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE source
(
  product varchar(20),
  amount decimal
)

CREATE TABLE cat
(
  category varchar(20),
  product varchar(20)
)
```

### Insert Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO source (product, amount) VALUES
('product1', 1.00),
('product2', 2.00),
('product3', 1.50),
('product4', 5.25)

INSERT INTO cat (category, product) VALUES
('Shirts', 'product1'),
('Green Shirt', 'product1'),
('Gadget', 'product1'),
('Food', 'product2'),
('Games', 'product4')
```

### My Trial Query:

```
DECLARE @categories varchar(200)
SET @categories = NULL

SELECT 
@categories = COALESCE(@categories + ',','') + cat.category
FROM cat

SELECT
DISTINCT source.product,
@categories
FROM cat
JOIN source on source.product = cat.product
```

### OUTPUT

```
PRODUCT     COLUMN_1
product1    Shirts,Green Shirt,Gadget,Food,Games
product2    Shirts,Green Shirt,Gadget,Food,Games
product4    Shirts,Green Shirt,Gadget,Food,Games
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
PRODUCT     COLUMN_1
product1    Shirts, Green Shirt, Gadget
product2    Gadget, Food
product4    Games
```

Comment: Read up on the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

Comment: Doing that right now. I will have to get used to SQL logic.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
  source.product,
  GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category) cats
FROM cat
  JOIN source on source.product = cat.product
GROUP BY source.product
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd835/3)

If you're trying to get a ', ' in between each category, use `SEPARATOR` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.  For example:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category separator ', ')
```

Comment: I cannot vote up your answer (15 rep req). I will try it out and comment here.