# need output for this query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table book with some columns, here is the table structure

```
book_id book_name book_cat_id book_pub_id book_price
1           A       cat-1        p-1         100
2           B       cat-2        p-2         150
3           C       cat-3        p-3         452
4           D       cat-4        p-4         452
5           E       cat-1        p-3         620
6           F       cat-2        p-4         300
7           G       cat-3        p-1         750
8           H       cat-4        p-2         125
```

I want output like this

```
book_pub_id      book_cat_id
     p-1          cat-1,cat-3
     p-2          cat-2,cat-4
     p-3          cat-3,cat-1
     p-4          cat-4,cat-2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Combine row values with comma and more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720129/mysql-combine-row-values-with-comma-and-more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT book_pub_id, GROUP_CONCAT(book_cat_id) book_cat_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY book_pub_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT book_pub_id, GROUP_CONCAT(book_cat_id) book_cat_id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY book_pub_id
```

[**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use GROUP_CONCAT() function of MySQl, the resulting query for the same will be

```
SELECT book_pub_id, GROUP_CONCAT(book_cat_id) book_cat_id
FROM Table
GROUP BY book_pub_id
```

Comment: This answer has been given, twice; also this particular query requires the term `Table` to be escaped, otherwise it will cause a parse error.